# Sorting multiple table rows with jQuery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the sortable function that comes with jQuery UI to enable me to reorder table rows.  It's working fine, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yrkcr69/4/) and below is my HTML and JS

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Fruit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Pear</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sticky">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Raspberry</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Mango</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


$(function(){
    $("table tbody").sortable();
});
```

However I want to me able to drag multiple rows at the same time.  Basically when you drag a `tr` if the `tr` directly below it has a class of `sticky` then that `tr` needs to be dragged with it.  So in my example any time you want to drag and reorder the "Pear" row the "Banana" row underneath will be moved with it.

I think it's possible to do this with a helper function but I'm really not sure where to start.  If someone could advise me on the best way to do it and point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: I have a solution that works, but it doesn't animate the "sticky" `tr`. Do you want the sticky item to be animated with the dragged item?

Comment: @Yass ideally yes, but a solution that doesn't animate is better than no solution.  If you show what you've done so far I might be able to do the animation part

Comment: Okay. I've sorted the animation aspect as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `start` event to check if the next `tr` has a `class` of `sticky` and insert it after the dragged item on the `stop` event. I'm making use of the `css` method to animate the "sticky" item.

```
$(function() {
  var $draggedItem, $stickyItem, itemWidth, itemHeight;
  $("table tbody").sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      $draggedItem = $(ui.item[0]);
      //Store the constant width and height values in variables.
      itemWidth = $draggedItem.width();
      itemHeight = $draggedItem.height();
      //next is called twice because a hidden "tr" is added when sorting.
      var $nextChild = $(ui.item[0]).next().next();
      if ($nextChild.hasClass('sticky')) {
        $stickyItem = $nextChild;
      }
      else {
        $stickyItem = undefined;
      }
    },
    sort: function() {
      if ($stickyItem != undefined) {
        //Set the css to match the dragged item's css, with the exception of "top", which includes an offset.
        $stickyItem.css({
          "z-index": $draggedItem.css('z-index'),
          "position": "absolute",
          "width": itemWidth,
          "height": itemHeight,
          "left": $draggedItem.css('left'),
          "top": $draggedItem.position().top + itemHeight,
        });
      }
    },
    stop: function() {
      if ($stickyItem != undefined) {
        $stickyItem.insertAfter($draggedItem);
        //Remove the style attribute to reset to thed default style.
        $stickyItem.removeAttr('style');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/gu3k31hr/)**

**Note:** You could improve the above further by only binding the `sort` and `stop` events if a sticky item exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  I had to add to a bit to make sure that you couldn't drag another row between a sticky row and the one above it.  But your well commented solution made it easy for me to understand

Comment: @Pattle Can you please share those lines which you have added!

Comment: @Pattle Share those extra lines of code which you have added please! I'm stuck in a similar situation :(

Comment: @Pattle c'mon! Show what you changed please. I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who'd like to prevent inserting rows between the sticky row and the one above it, here's a slightly modified version of Yass's solution:

```
$(function () {
    let $draggedItem, $stickyItem, itemWidth, itemHeight, cancelSortable;
    $("table tbody").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $draggedItem = $(ui.item[0]);
            //Store the constant width and height values in variables.
            itemWidth = $draggedItem.width();
            itemHeight = $draggedItem.height();
            //next is called twice because a hidden "tr" is added when sorting.
            let $nextChild = $(ui.item[0]).next().next();
            if ($nextChild.hasClass('sticky')) {
                $stickyItem = $nextChild;
            } else {
                $stickyItem = undefined;
            }
        },
        sort: function (event, ui) {
            if ($stickyItem !== undefined) {
                //Set the css to match the dragged item's css, with the exception of "top", which includes an offset.
                $stickyItem.css({
                    "z-index": $draggedItem.css('z-index'),
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "width": itemWidth,
                    "height": itemHeight,
                    "left": $draggedItem.css('left'),
                    "top": $draggedItem.position().top + itemHeight,
                });
            }
            if (ui.placeholder.next() !== undefined && ui.placeholder.next().hasClass("sticky")) {
                ui.placeholder.hide();
                cancelSortable = true;
            } else {
                ui.placeholder.show();
                cancelSortable = false;
            }
        },
        stop: function () {
            if (cancelSortable) {
                $(this).sortable("cancel");
            }
            if ($stickyItem !== undefined) {
                $stickyItem.insertAfter($draggedItem);
                //Remove the style attribute to reset to the default style.
                $stickyItem.removeAttr('style');
            }
        }
    });
});
```